# Do I need a Mac to develop Xamarin.iOS apps?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

A need to develop iOS and Android apps.

If I choose Xamarin, would I need a Mac to build apps for iOS?

Comment: Yes you will, as per dev guidelines.

Comment: Yes, but that's not unique to the Xamarin platform, you'll need a Mac regardless of what platform you use.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you will, but that'll be true regardless of what platform you choose for development. It's just as true for native development, Cordova, etc. as it is for Xamarin.Forms and Xamarin.iOS.

Note that it's possible to lease a Mac in the cloud.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Some jealous people, I up voted you ;)